# Constant Current Source BJT

Tags: bjt, constant-current

[image: Multisim plot of IsubL over RsubL][image: The constant current network and problem statement with values]

I am stuck trying to determine the applicable formula for the load current. I have used $$I_b = \frac{V_{\text{in}}-V_{\text{be}}}{(\beta+1)R_{\text{e}}}$$ and then $$I_{\text{L}}= \beta I_\text{b}$$

The problem is I can't find a proper relationship for why the current drops or increases as \$R_{\text{L}}\$ changes. Can someone please just point me in the right direction? I want to solve it myself, just need to know what I'm missing.

Comment: Do you know what saturation is? And for what Rc value your BJT's will start to enter into saturation region?

Comment: When they write "assume \$\beta\$ is a high value" do they want you to assume it is \$\beta=\infty\$?

Comment: I know the lab book says 100mV but doesn't say the resistor value. And this is where our text does a horrible job. It asks what the highest value of R_L can be before the basic equation is no longer valid, and I assume this is where the curve in the plot is non-linear. I just don't have any clue how to get there mathematically

Comment: The \Beta value given is 200 so, this lab book is seriously vague on some topics

Comment: @WARmachin3 Basically, this is just an emitter follower circuit. The emitter voltage will follow the base voltage (\$V_\text{IN}\$), less a \$V_\text{BE}\$ drop. That voltage, combined with \$R_\text{E}\$, determines the emitter current. This emitter current, less any base current required for recombination, is the collector current. That collector current causes a voltage drop on \$R_\text{C}\$. You have to subtract that voltage drop from the supply voltage rail. It stays in active mode until the collector voltage reaches the base voltage, \$V_\text{IN}\$. (Or less, if your text allows.)

Comment: @jonk OMG that makes so much since. So when I_L*R_L = V_in  is when I start getting the non linear drop in current flow?

Comment: @WARmachin3 The BJT collector will "act like" a current source that simply passes along the emitter current until \$\left[V_\text{C}=V_\text{CC}-I_\text{L}\cdot R_\text{L}\right]\approx V_\text{IN}\$. At that point the BJT just barely begins to move from active mode gradually into increasingly deeper saturation as the collector voltage declines a little more. It's not until \$V_\text{C}\$ forward-biases by about \$500\:\text{mV}\$ or so, that it nears fuller saturation and then the collector acts like a voltage source, instead, and the load current mostly stops changing.

Comment: @jonk TYVM! This has helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In active mode (not saturated):

\$\begin{align*}
I_\text{L}&=I_\text{E}-\frac{I_\text{E}}{\beta+1}\\\\
I_\text{E}&=\frac{V_\text{IN}-V_\text{BE}}{R_\text{E}}\\\\
V_\text{C}&=V_\text{CC}-I_\text{L}\cdot R_\text{L}
\end{align*}\$

Saturation just barely begins to happen right at the point where \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{IN}\$, which is right at the point where the BC junction of the BJT just begins to become forward-biased. But it's not really very noticeable at that point.

If you were designing an amplifier stage where you wanted the BJT to ***always*** be in active mode and never saturated at all, then you'd definitely want to maintain \$V_\text{C}\ge \left[V_\text{B}=V_\text{IN}\right]\$. But if you wanted to actually readily ***see*** some significant change in the "linear" declining collector voltage behavior, this doesn't really start to happen enough to be very visible until \$V_\text{C}\$ nears about \$500\:\text{mV}\$ below the base voltage (in your case, \$V_\text{IN}\$.) So you use what's appropriate to the situation at hand.

Let's call the variable defining saturation as \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$. If you set \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}=V_\text{BE}\$, then you are using a definition where saturation is defined to occur when it is just barely starting to happen. On the other hand, if you set \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}=V_\text{BE}-500\:\text{mV}=200\:\text{mV}\$ (in your case, let's say), then you are using a definition where saturation is defined to occur when it moving into deep saturation. This latter definition is where you really see the ***cornering*** voltage at the collector.

Either way, the general equation for when saturation begins is:

$$V_\text{E}=V_\text{IN}-V_\text{BE}=\left(V_\text{CC}-V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\right)\cdot\frac{R_\text{E}}{R_\text{E}+\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\,R_\text{L}}$$

(Solve for \$V_\text{IN}\$, of course, if you want that value.)

It may not be immediately obvious to you. But this is the same equation you'd get from the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0RlNN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In effect, this as a voltage divider between \$R_\text{E}\$ and \$R_\text{L}\$. The very slight adjustments involve reducing \$V_\text{CC}\$ by whatever value you pick for \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$ and by a very minor adjustment in the value of \$R_\text{L}\$ to account for the fact that only \$\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\$ of the emitter current becomes a collector current. Otherwise, it's really simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have the variation in the large signal model with Vbe (and beta) as the transistor heats, but there is more to it than that.

I think you should use the [hybrid-pi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-pi_model) for the transistor. With a "stiff" voltage source on the base, the output resistance of your current sink is ro, which is related to the [Early Voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_effect) Va that you will find in a transistor SPICE model.

[image]